# Laravel filtering the 'with' results

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a web app which includes a query like the below:

```
$entry = Entry::with([
    'elements',
    'competition.groups.fields',
    'competition.groups.reviews'
])->find($id);
```

What I'd like to do is add something along the lines of:

```
$entry = Entry::with([
    'elements',
    'competition.groups.fields',
    'competition.groups.reviews' -> where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
])->find($id);
```

So I'd like to grab the reviews which belong to the entry, where the review's user_id also matches the currently logged in user. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a closure for filtering `with` results:

```
$entry = Entry::with([
    'elements',
    'competition.groups.fields',
    'competition.groups.reviews' => function($q){
        $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id()); // Replaced Auth::user()->id with a shortcut: Auth::id()
    }
])->find($id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code too..

```
$entry = Entry::select('elements', 'competition.groups.fields', 'competition.groups.reviews')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

This code will grab a collection of  `Entries` which belong to the current user who is logged in.

If no entries present `Entries` collection count will be zero. If some entries exists, then you can loop through the collection and grab entries properties.